# Fscan with structure

Tags: c, scanf, singly-linked-list

I'm reading from text file which contains 3 columns (coordinate id, x cord and y cord).
All values are spaced out with tab (\t). When I try to use fscanf() to make list it won't print mine 1st line and it prints out last line 2 times.

```
while ((fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fptr)) != NULL)
{
    fscanf(fptr,"%d%f%f", &id, &xc, &yc);
    tempValue.xyID = id;
    tempValue.x = xc;
    tempValue.y = yc;
    addToList(nodeID++, tempValue);
}
printList();
```

The code above is not working with scanf, but when I do this:

```
while ((fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fptr)) != NULL)
{
    tempValue.xyID = atoi(strtok(buffer,"\t"));
    tempValue.x = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
    tempValue.y = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
    addToList(nodeID++, tempValue);
}
printList();
```

The code above works perfectly, and I wanna know what am I doing wrong with fscanf.Thank you!

Comment: You forgot the `\t` separator in your fscanf call...

Comment: fscanf(fptr,"%d\t%f\t%f", &id, &xc, &yc); , tried this its the same :/

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] including a) the input you've given, b) the output you're getting and definition of `id`, `xc`, `yc` **and** `tempValue`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `fgets()` to read a line from a file into memory, you need to use `sscanf(buffer, ...)` to scan that line. If you call `fscanf(fptr, ...)`, you are basically discarding the line you just read, and reading the next bit of data from the file.

The reason you see the last line twice, is most likely because `fscanf()` was called when you already reached the end of the file. If it cannot read any data, the variables you pass to `fscanf()` will not be overwritten. You are not checking the return value of `fscanf()` to ensure you actually read new data, instead you always call `addToList()`, which will then add an item to the list using the values stored by the previous call to `fscanf()`.

Your second attempt works because you now are actually parsing the data that you read into the buffer. Note that again you are not checking all the return values of the functions you call for errors. If you would try to read a file that contains a line with less than three items, then your second version will crash because `strtok()` would return `NULL`, and then you are effectively calling `atoi(NULL)`. Also, `atoi()` silently ignores any errors, such as when the string it tries to parse doesn't contain a valid number, and it will instead return 0. It is better to use `strtol()` if you want to be sure that you parsed a value correctly.

Comment: Thank you for good reply. But why does it still prints last line 2 times tho?

Comment: If `fscanf()` is called, but fails to read the data, it will return an error value, but will not change the variables you try to read into. You ignored the return value, and are just printing values from the previous call to `fscanf()`.

Comment: I replaced fscanf with sscanf as you said. I am not using fscanf in program anymore

Comment: Great. Ensure you also check the return value of `sscanf()`!